# Nginx configuration equivalent for Apache

Tags: regex, apache, nginx, configuration

I would like some help to convert those Nginx rules to work for Apache :

```
location ~ ^/video/([a-zA-Z0-9=\?]+)$ {
  rewrite ^/video/(.*)$ /video/ break;
}
location /video {
  ssi on;
}
location /http-bind {
  proxy_pass      http://localhost:5280/http-bind;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

After some research, I have found :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/meet/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^/meet/(.*)$ /meet/ [PT]
ProxyPreserveHost Off

<Location "/meet/http-bind">
  RequestHeader set Host "localhost"
  ProxyPass http://localhost:5280/http-bind
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5280/http-bind
</Location>
```

But this configuration doesn't work well... Can you help me to modify this configuration ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't ask us to do the work of converting a whole config, ask about a problem or a specific rule.

Comment: i think you have a typo. first you write `video` and in your apache config you write `meet`